# Weird Response of strtotime PHP

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have a code where I'm using **strtotime()** to get the **date timestamp** in PHP.

Have encountered a weird response of it.

Case 1. I got a date like "Tue Jul 2 6pm" : **strtotime gives bool(false).**

```
<?php $case1 = strtotime("Tue July 2 6pm"); 
var_dump($case1);
?>
```

Case 2. If the date is like "Tue Jul 2 6:00pm" :strtotime gives timestamp  "**1562115600**" taking year as current year.

```
<?php $case2 = strtotime("Tue July 2 6:00pm"); 
var_dump($case2);
?>
```

Can anyone help me out. Why did **strtotime gave bool(false)** for the first case ?

What can be done to fix this, Please help ?

Comment: Use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` and a format that matches the input. `strtotime()` is almost magic, but occasionally it will guess wrong and fail

Answer (score 4):

[check php manual for strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC),
>
> Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise.

To fix,it must be converted into a valid format

[valid date time formats in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Answer (score -1):

To your first point:

```
<?php
date_create("Tue Jul 2 6pm");
var_dump(date_get_last_errors());
```

Gives an error: 'The timezone could not be found in the database'. Which means it is not recognized as a valid date/time string. You can explicitly specify the format:

```
date_create_from_format("D F j ga", "Tue Jul 2 6pm")
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation about **why** there is such an error message?

Comment: No. I am not familiar with php internals. For anybody interested here is the source code of the strtotime function https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.3.23/ext/date/php_date.c#L1397